Need advice on proxying API requests from NGINX to EC2 server hosting Flask API with Gunicorn
Bfore I get to my question; here is a high-level breakdown of how my architecture looks:
There is an Enterprise NGINX server for the company I work for that listens for traffic for numerous backend services. The specific team I am on has an AWS account and we have an EC2 Ubuntu instance that is hosting Flask with Gunicorn acting as the WSGI. I created my Gunicorn service file in the path /etc/sytemd/system/data_ingest.service
Here is how it looks:
[Unit]
Description=Gunicorn instance to serve data ingestion Flask app
After=network.target

[Service]
User=<userAccount>
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/<userAccount>/<projRoot>
Enviornment="PATH=/home/<userAccount>/<projRoot>/.venv/bin/"
ExecStart=/home/<userAccount>/<projRoot>/.venv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind 0.0.0.0:8443 -m 007 wsgi:app
 
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

I created this file after following this guide provided by DigitalOcean . The only thing I changed is the --bind parameter. As you can see, it is --bind 0.0.0.0:8443 but DigitalOcean says to use --bind unix:<myProject>.sock  .
My question is: If I want NGINX to forward HTTPS 443 traffic to my Flask server, do I need the bind property to be like this (--bind unix:<myProject>.sock ) ? I want my server to be listening on port 8443; it's a security guideline requirement made by my company. And the only way I have been able to start this gunicorn service and get the API to work is with this bind configuration --bind 0.0.0.0:8443 . Something to note: I have not set up the configuration for nginx to my server yet.

If the Nginx proxy and Flask instance are hosted on different computers, then --bind unix:<myProject>.sock will not work. Unix domain sockets only work between two processes on the same computer. If they are different computers, you need TCP/IP sockets, like 0.0.0.0:8443.

@NickODell Thank you for that input. Honestly working with sockets is completely new to me. So, how I currently have it set up is all I need?

Given that they want you to use 8443, I assume they want you to use HTTPS rather than HTTP between the nginx server and your server, which this configuration won't do. You'd have to ask your security team if that's their intention. If so, you can either configure gunicorn for SSL, or use a second instance of nginx running on the same server as Flask to terminate the SSL connection.

I used certbot to create a free SSL certificate and automatically redirect every request to HTTPS
here is a more detailed guide
https://certbot.eff.org/instructions?ws=nginx&os=pip
I believe you can change the port from the NGINX configuration, I used community versions and usually made changes from /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/mysite.com  and it is what I'm familiar with. Here is a guide on running SSL on a non-standard port:
https://serverfault.com/questions/828130/how-to-run-nginx-ssl-on-non-standard-port
I hope you will fix the issue
Note: If you want you can also run NGINX on a custom IP or a Local one from this configuration
